# IllegalStateException occurs when using Jackson @JsonDeserialize annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to use a custom deserializer in Jackson to deserialize some json objects. However, when I try to have the ObjectMapper read the json, the following exception occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationIntrospector returned Class com.Geometry.GeometryDeserializer; expected Class<JsonDeserializer>
```

I'm somewhat at a loss of what to do here, since it seems like the AnnotationIntrospector is complaining that my GeometryDeserializer is not a subclass of JsonDeserializer, when it clearly is.

Here's where I create the Object Mapper:

```
public void deserializeJson(String json) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Feature.class, MixIn.class);
    Feature feature = mapper.readValue(json, Feature.class);
}
```

...my Mix In class:

```
abstract class MixIn {
    @JsonDeserialize(using=GeometryDeserializer.class)
    abstract void setGeometry(Geometry geometry);
}
```

...and my deserializer:

```
public class GeometryDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Geometry> {
    @Override
    public Geometry deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        //stuff happens
    }
}
```

Any feedback/assistance would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: you are accidentally mixing up Jackson 1.x and Jackson 2.x types? Class names are mostly the same, but live in different packages -- things work when using one set of classes, but IDEs may cause accidental mix-ups.